# How to read parameters of Azure function HTTP request and respond with a file from blob storage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm building an Azure Function app and have had some issues trying to proxy requests (for data capture purposes) and still respond with the requested files. Essentially what I'm trying to accomplish is:

1. Client requests file via GET parameter on an Azure Function endpoint (not its blob storage location)
2. Function logs some metadata to table storage (e.g. IP address, timestamp, file name, etc.)
3. Function locates the desired file in blob storage and forwards it to the client as if Step 2 didn't occur

I've tried an approach using Q (outlined [here](https://medium.com/@hosarsiph.valle/download-files-with-azure-functions-node-js-35d4f8d08cb8)) with no luck, and I haven't been able to narrow the issue down (beyond standard 500 errors).

The tutorial above basically goes as follows:

```
const rawFile = await q.nfcall(fs.readFile, blobUrl);

const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(rawFile, ‘base64’);

context.res = {
   status: 202,
   body: fileBuffer,
   headers: {
      "Content-Disposition": "attachment; examplefile.mp3;"
   }
};

context.done();
```

I've hit a bit of a wall and I'm struggling to find a solution to what I thought would be a common problem (i.e. simply logging download metadata to a table). I'm new to Azure and so far I'm finding things a bit tedious... Is there a simple way of doing this?

**Edit:** Based on the response I get from `context.bindings.myFile.length` I *think* I've been able to retrieve a file from blob storage, but I haven't yet been able to send it back in the response. I've tried the following:

```
context.res = {
    status: 202,
    body: context.bindings.myFile,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=' + fileName,
        'Content-Length': context.bindings.myFile.length
    }
};
```

**Edit 2:** I think this is pretty much solved - I overlooked the `methods` and `route` in the HTTP input part of the answer below. Looks like I'm able to dynamically retrieve blobs based on the `GET` request and use them as inputs, and I've been able to get them sent back to the client as well. My HTTP response now looks like this:

```
context.res = {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
        'Content-Length': context.bindings.myFile.length,
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg'
    },
    body: context.bindings.myFile,
    isRaw: true
};
```

Comment: did you try my suggestion?

Comment: I _think_ I've managed to retrieve the blob file (using `.length` returns a value similar to what I'm expecting), but so far I haven't been able to send it back in the response. I'll update the original post with what I've tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me paraphrase what you asked:

- You want just to retrieve blob storage object upon http request.

I think it is worth looking into [bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings). They simplify the integration with other Azure services - Storage Accounts, Service Bus, Twilio - and Function Apps.

In your case it should be an [input binding for blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#input---javascript-example). As one way to achieve it you need to [customize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#input---javascript-example) your route in the http trigger part of *function.json* as follows: `file/{fileName}`. Then you use `fileName` in input binding definition in the same *function.json*.

I think *function.json* should like this:

```
{
    "bindings": [
    {
        "type": "httpTrigger",
        "name": "req",
        "direction": "in",
        "methods": [ "get" ],
        "route": "file/{fileName}"
    },
    {
      "name": "myFile",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "your-container-name/{fileName}",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
        "type": "http",
        "name": "res",
        "direction": "out"
    }
    ]
}
```

With your *index.js* as follows:

```
module.exports = function(context, req) {
    context.log('Node.js Queue trigger function processed', context.bindings.myFile);
    const fileToReturn = context.bindings.myFile;
    // you return it here with context.res = ...
    context.done();
};
```

You also superficially mentioned the logging that is not part of your question but is mentioned. I recommend looking into [Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring). It might serve the purpose.