# how to save logs to adls for every https request of azure function

Tags: azure, https, azure-functions, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a Azure function with HTTP trigger. For every HTTP request I need to save the logs of  details  the of post request to ADLS like time of trigger and request params.

Can anyone help me how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the Workaround I did to store the Azure Function Logs in ADLS Gen 2 where the logs contains the Function Execution Time, Started Time, Execution Result, etc.**

- To Create the Function App in ADLS Gen 2, First, you need to create the Storage Account of type ADLS Gen 2.
- When you're creating the Storage Account, Check the box of `Enable hierarchical namespace` to create an ADLS Gen 2 Account.

[image]

After Creating an ADLS Storage account, create a function app in that storage account using PowerShell Command: (For example `DotNet` Stack)

```
New-AzFunctionApp -Name <APP_NAME> -ResourceGroupName AzureFunctionsQuickstart-rg -StorageAccount <STORAGE_NAME> -Runtime dotnet -FunctionsVersion 3 -Location '<REGION>'
```

- Created Http Trigger Function App through Portal in the Function App and it is running successfully with the POST Request.
- Enable the Application Insights Resource on your Function App in the Portal.
- All the logs will be stored in the path:

***ADLS Storage Account > File Shares > Your Function App > LogFiles > Application > Functions > Function > Your Function Name > here you can see the logs.***

[image]
[image]

[image]

Suppose, ***Function Key*** is also a one of the parameter in Azure Function URL.

**By default, this info will not be logged but we can customize the code to log this parameter and in the Traces table of Application insights, this information can be available.**

```
const  string key_Claim =  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2017/07/functions/claims/keyid";
var claim = req.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type  == key_Claim);
if(claim !=  null)
{
log.LogInformation(  "The call was made using {0} named key", claim.Value);
 }
```

[image]

**In Application Insights [Logs]**

[image]

***The above Workaround I did in .Net Stack and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57643760/how-to-read-parameters-of-azure-function-http-request-and-respond-with-a-file-fr) is an example code related to read parameters of Azure Function and store it in a blob files using NodeJS.***